# Need to start a pro version of existing project from git, any ideas

Tags: git, version, bitbucket

i am new to git management.
I need to start a new project from existing git. (i am using bitbucket, sourcetree).

Initial version is basic version, now i need to make a pro version of it. I need to get the copy of this basic version and start working on it for pro features. Now, when i copy and upload it to bitbucket it says it already has the same git and is hosted. I want to change it and host as a new version of git on bitbucket.

Answer (score 1):

You can just clone it to a new name:

```
$ git clone project project_pro
```

Comment: doing it that way, it will have .git repo of project in project_pro and i need to have a separate git for this. so that i can make updates for both separately.

Comment: No, they will be separate. The only connection will be that `project_pro` will have `project` as its 'origin' remote. You can just go into `project_pro` and do `git remote remove origin` to remove that, though, and then they will definitely be two entirely separate git repos, the second being a copy of the first.